# Merge [free-trade] and [trade]

Tags: discussion, tags

I think we should merge the [free-trade](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-trade) and [trade](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trade) tags. The degree to which trade is "free trade" and who benefits from "free" trade is a big part of what discussions of trade are about. There might be an occasional question about trade that doesn't hit on these topics, but the overlap is too great to merit a distinct free-trade tag that is completely covered by the trade tag.

Comment: I see you started a tag synonym vote. I think it should be done the other way around. All free-trade questions are about trade, but not vice versa. I cannot start a tag synonym vote for the opposite while your vote is on-going.

Comment: @JJJ I'm not sure I understand. I thought I went to free-trade and suggested trade as a synonym.

Comment: I don't think so. I cannot vote, even though I have enough rep from the trade tag, but not from the free-trade tag.

Comment: If you went to free trade and suggested trade as a synonym, then you are pointing trade to free trade (so trade would disappear and be replaced by free trade).  If you want to make free trade point to trade, you have to go to trade and list free trade as a synonym.  You suggest synonyms on the *recipient* of the relationship.

Comment: @Brythan and JJJ you both are right, I go the direction wrong. I can't seem to remove the suggested synonym and switch them. I flagged this for moderator attention.